# exclude a page from windows authentication in asp.net

Tags: .net, asp.net, authentication, windows-authentication

i am using windows authentication for my site and want to exclude a folder under the root. But not able to do it like how we exclude a page in forms authentication.

```
  <location path="handlers">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Is there any other way we have? i have gone through web... but could not find any other answer..

could any one of you help me in this..?

i am using IIS 7.5, Vs 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Check the directory security of that perticular folder ('handlers' or whatever) in IIS, make sure that anonymous access is enabled for that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can place another web.config in the folder you are trying to exclude with this

```
<location>
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: HI guys

nothing is working out. Is there any thing wrong am i doing..?

  <location path="testauth.htm">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

now, i am not thinking about a folder..but about a a html page in my root of the website. But, it stilll asks for the authentication...cant see whats wrong..?

not getting much help from google....also..

is any one tried this kind of thing before.. .? i am sure some one must have.. and my iis 7.5(windows 7)